# Is it possible to have EF Core Migrations with separate class library (Not in same solution)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am in process of making the c# .NET standard library which eventually should be published on nuget. 
Since library encapsulates communication with database, I wanted to use EF core (Code First) to setup database model.
Users of the library should be able to generate database model for arbitrary database(i.e. user should specify connection string) from code, which is contained in library, i.e. migrations should be located in the library.

My concern is: Is this even supported scenario by EF core.
So far browsing the the internet resulted with no info about this scenario.

My questions are:

1. Is this scenario somehow supported in EF core.
2. If not then what are the ways to implement library which contains database model(either in the form of SQL script or migration code), user of the library should be able to specify connection string and generate database model.

Comment: [EF Core supports migrations on a separate project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects). But I guess that's not what you're looking for?

Comment: You are right, In my case migrations must be located in same assembly where DbContext is?

Comment: I've implemented this in my project. Data Access.EF configures the context and the DataAccess.EF.X registers de context for the DB provider. https://github.com/taconaut/Sppd.TeamTuner/tree/master/Backend Hope it helps